# How to create a package for different files?

Tags: java, package

How do I create a Java package for different files? I have tried 
the following. What have I done wrong? And what is the 
right procedure?

The first file is:

```
package dil;
public class Hello
{
    Support sp=new Support();
    int i=sp.tin();
    public void man()
    {
       System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The second file is:

```
package dil;
class Support
{
    public int tin()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Now while I compile hello.java it shows these errors:

```
Hello:4:cannot find symbol
symbol: class Support
location: class dil.hello
Support sp=new Support();
               ^
Hello:4:cannot find symbol
symbol: class Support
location: class dil.hello
Support sp=new Support();
^
```

Where is the problem and how can I put both
these files in a package?

The files are in c:\src.

Comment: Something is not right here. Would you give use your folder structure for this two files? and How exactly you compile it (including the current directory of the compilation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming UNIX / Linux pathnames, a UNIX shell, etc, you need the following file structure:

```
/some/where/dil
/some/where/dil/hello.java
/some/where/dil/Support.java
```

Then set `$CLASSPATH` to `/some/where`, and compile using the commands

```
cd /some/where
javac dil/*.java
```

and run using

```
java dil.hello
```

Alternatively, you can tell `java` and `javac` what classpath to use with the `-cp` command line option.

You should also fix the following errors in the code:

1. Change the name of the "hello" class to "Hello", and rename the source file to match.  Strictly speaking this is not an error, but it is a gross violation of the standard for naming Java classes.
2. You declare a member as "ten" but refer to it as "tin".  Fix one or the other.
3. The entry point method in the "hello" class should be called "main" not "man", and should have a signature `public static void main(String[] arg)`.  If you don't fix these the code will compile, but the `java` command won't find the entry point and will fail.

Comment: The filename should be Hello.java with a capital 'H'.

Comment: Yes ... that's the problem NOW! But if you look at the original version of the question, the class "hello" was in a file called "Hello.java".  I give up.  Somebody just does not get it ...

Answer (score 1):

Although the Support class is not public, that would not be a problem as both classes share the same package. My guess would be that you did not put both source files into a directory according to their packagename and call the javac compiler from the current directory where hello.java resides.

If a class is in package a.b this means the project structure should contain a folder ./a/b containing yourclass.java.

In your case, try to create a folder named ./dil, put your source files in it and call javac from its parent folder.

Comment: Actually I have put both the files in the same directory,and edit
the ten() and make it tin(), but still its not working....

Comment: The crux probably lies in the fact that javac needs a classpath that points to the root package folder. (examle: if your source is in /tmp/dil, run the compiler from /tmp as sourcepath.)

Answer (score 1):

See [Creating and Using Packages](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/package/packages.html) in Sun's Java Tutorials to learn all the details of using packages in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted some things you have to check:

- class *hello* starts with a lower case
- class *hello* calls for *sp.ten()* instead of *sp.tin()*

Answer (score 0):

**`Support`** isn't `public`. Make it public and try again.

Comment: It doesn't have to be public as the classes are in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try using one of the free IDEs like Netbeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ CE.  This will help you start coding rather than setting everything up the hard way.

BTW: These IDEs have quick fixes for most common problems so they not only give you the error but give you options to fix them and do it for you.